# How to analyze large amount of URI logs

Tags: algorithm, uri, analysis

I have about 1 million URI logs of user activity on my network, I want to know how many of those 1 million are for Facebook, how many are for Twitter, and so on..
It's easy to link URIs like cdn.xyz.twitter.com , platform.twitter.com to Twitter 
However, the problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to link no more than 40% of the URLs captured to real websites, a URL like xys.1234.com can be something in facebook for example, but there isn't a link between that URL and facebook.com domain, thus will just be listed as a stand-alone website, which is wrong (or not what I want).

Also, all API calls won’t also be easily linked to their domains because some websites are maybe using amazon web services and that's what is being logged.

And Many of the URIs are generated from ad services, I want to know where this ad is generated from ( on what website or mobile application did the user click on the ad? ).

Snapshots of URIs so you would understand the whole picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjKfj.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eanAT.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to match up outgoing requests? How do you expect to know that a user who accessed xyz.1234.com did it through Facebook rather than independently by typing the URL into the address bar? Or by clicking a link from some other page? Your log doesn't contain information that tells you which URLs are linked from which page. Without another source of information, you can't be sure.

You could examine the requests for multiple users and *infer* relationships. That is, if you notice that all (or a majority of) requests to xyz.1234.com occur after a Facebook request, you can infer that the request occurred as a result of a click on a Facebook page. Doing so will require some interesting pattern matching. How well it works will depend on how much data you have to work with, how well you write the pattern matching, and how much time you're willing to let the algorithm run.

There's no simple answer, though. If you don't have data that explicitly says, "this request was made by clicking on a link from Twitter," then you have to either get another source of information or you have to write code that will infer that information.